# Javascript sort array on property array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this array of users that looks something like this:

```
[{
    userName: 'Jim',
    roles: ['Member']
}, {
    userName: 'Adam',
    roles: ['Administrator']
}, {
    userName: 'Suzy',
    roles: ['SuperUser']
}, {
    userName: 'Greg',
    roles: ['SuperUser']
}, {
    userName: 'Ady',
    roles: ['Administrator']
}, {
    userName: 'Jeremy',
    roles: ['Administrator']
}]
```

I would like to sort this array by it's roles.
I tried doing this:

```
items.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aValue = a.roles[0];
    var bValue = b.roles[0];

    if (aValue < bValue) return -1;
    if (aValue > bValue) return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

But it doesn't do what I expect. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: You're returning `-1` for two comparison cases. One should return `1`, depending on your sort order (ascending or descending)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method for string comparison inside `sort()`.

```js
var data = [{"userName":"Jim","roles":["Member"]},{"userName":"Adam","roles":["Administrator"]},{"userName":"Suzy","roles":["SuperUser"]},{"userName":"Greg","roles":["SuperUser"]},{"userName":"Ady","roles":["Administrator"]},{"userName":"Jeremy","roles":["Administrator"]}]

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.roles[0].localeCompare(b.roles[0])
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

give this a shot

```
function SortByRole(a, b){
  var aRole = a.roles[0];
  var bRole = b.roles[0]; 
  return ((aRole < bRole) ? -1 : ((aRole > bRole) ? 1 : 0));
}

array.sort(SortByRole);
```